# import Data from Grid table to Database table Sql Windows

Tags: mysql, guptateamdeveloper

I have after some struggle succeeded to import excel data to a Grid table in TD and also loaded this up into a SqlBase table.  I have struggled with one issue.  If I have an excel file with header row and the first row of data is the second row, the import will be done, but the data is NOT like the date in the Grid when I look into SqlBase.  If I however, put a BLANK line after the header row it seems to be ok.

Anybody can comment on this or tell me why or how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the context of grid window to first row before importing. Which can be done using the function *SalTblSetContext()*. If you are not applied the latest SPF then apply it. Which is available at [link](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/Team_Developer_Downloads).